# How do I change the line_num object in csv_reader?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I am working on a vending machine simulation for school work and I would like to print the items in the machine with a for loop from a CSV file. this works but if the for loop to print the stock list is repeated, the loop does not work as the line_num attribute has already hit the end of the CSV file. Here is the code:

```
    import csv
ITEM_COUNT = 0 #Counter for the FOR loop that prints the stocklist

OPEN_STOCK_READ = open("stock.csv", "r") #Sets up a variable for reading the stocklist
OPEN_STOCK_AMEND = open("stock.csv","a") #Sets up a variable for amending the stocklist
STOCK_READ = csv.reader(OPEN_STOCK_READ)
STOCK_AMEND = csv.reader(OPEN_STOCK_AMEND)

while True:
    ITEM_COUNT = 0
    for line in STOCK_READ:
        ITEM_COUNT = ITEM_COUNT + 1
        print("{0} - {1} - {2} in stock".format(ITEM_COUNT,line[0],line[1]))
```

Here is the CSV file I am working in:

```
Coca Cola,10
Monster,10
Monster Ultra,10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a context manager to handle reading the list, and the file will remain open only for the operation it contains.

```
import csv

def get_stock_count():
    ITEM_COUNT = 0
    with open('stock.csv', 'r') as STOCK_READ:
        reader = csv.reader(STOCK_READ)
        for line in reader:
            ITEM_COUNT = ITEM_COUNT + 1
            print("{0} - {1} - {2} in stock".format(ITEM_COUNT,line[0],line[1]))
    return ITEM_COUNT
```

Once the contained `for` loop is complete, the file will close. Any time you wish to get a new `ITEM_COUNT`, just call `get_stock_count` again.

Comment: A context manager could be a nice idea, unfortunately your code opens the file before entering the context manager. So after first iteration, the underlying file will be closed (OP's question was about the way to process the file more than once...)

Comment: Updated my answer to be more clear. I'm suggesting that there is really no reason to iterate over the same list unless the file has been altered.  As a result, the file should never stay open outside of the counter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not a `line_num` attribute, but simply that the file pointer is at end of file. So you have two options here:

- open the file on each iteration of the while loop:

  ```
  while True:         // maybe a non ever lasting loop could be better...
      with open("stock.csv", "r+") as OPEN_STOCK_READ:
          STOCK_READ = csv.reader(OPEN_STOCK_READ)
          for row in STOCK_READ:
              # process row
  ```
- rewind the file at end of loop :

  ```
  with open("stock.csv", "r+") as OPEN_STOCK_READ:
      while True:
          STOCK_READ = csv.reader(OPEN_STOCK_READ)
          for row in STOCK_READ:
              # process row
              ...
          OPEN_STOCK_READ.seek(0,0)   # rewind the file object
  ```

Also note that to update a file, you should open it only once in "r+" mode.

Comment: I will use the second method, thanks :). The loop is never ending because the objectives require the program to be “always on”